Vite React app says no webpage found for localhost:5173 - what could be the issue here?

I tried to make a React app with Vite and I used npm run dev to run it but webpage says no webpage was found for localhost:5173. I don't know how to fix it because everything seems fine in the code part, also there are no errors in the terminal. Could there be a problem in package.json?

"it says" - what says? How can we say whether there is a problem in a file you're not showing us?

mb on that i meant the webpage by "it"
edit: mb = my bad

so i found a solution for this problem, my index.html file wasnt in the root, instead i had put it in public folder. also i had another issue with the styles.css file in which i had imported it in index.jsx and also had a link tag for it in index.html which was causing issue so i removed it from index.jsx and it solved it.
